# What is the difference if a Views' "head" tag has attribute "runat" or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I create any views in my application in ASP.NET then I see that

```
<head runat="server">
```

If I change it to

```
<head>
```

what is difference between these two conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define the `head` tag with the `runat` attribute set to `"server"`, the value of `Title` attribute in the page declaration will be shown.

Let's assume you've defined a page with the following declaration on top of the code:

*MyPage.aspx*:

```
<%@ Page title="My Website"...
```

Let's also assume that the master page's `head` tag is defined as follows:

*Site.Master*:

```
<head runat="server"></head>
```

Then the resulting markup will look like the following:

```
<head><title>My Website</title></head>
```

If you define the `head` tag without the `runat` attribute set, the title defined by the `Title` attribute just won't be displayed, and you have to set the title directly in the markup:

```
<head><title>My Website (Title has been set manually)</title></head>
```

---

**Update**: 
If you create a new MVC project with Visual Studio, the master page will contain an `asp:ContentPlaceHolder` within the `title` tag as default:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
</head>
```

The `asp:ContentPlaceHolder`'s content will override the value of the `Title` attribute you've set in the page declaration, as correctly noted in a comment to this answer by the user [Yngvebn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325836/yngvebn)

Comment: Yes, this is true. But it seems that if you also define the <title> tag in your view, that overrides the Title="" attribute in the <%@ Page directive.

Comment: @Yngvebn The view shouldn't contain the `head` tag, but the master page should, since it's the site-wide page template; the view should serve the content.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but the standard setup in MVC is the asp:ContentPlaceHolder for title, so in the site.master you're getting a 
    <title>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />
    </title>

This overrides the Title in the page-directive.

Comment: @Yngvebn That was exactly what I was going to write, but I somehow managed to lose my reply by doing a deadly " *Previous page in history* " mouse gesture with Opera. Well, back to my reply: Yes, you're right in this case; I actually noticed that the previous edit of my answer didn't include the complete definition of the master page's `head` tag, although I mentioned it in the previous line. Nevertheless, I've updated my answer now; I've included a clean declaration of the `head` tag

Comment: @Yngvebn Thanks :) I've updated my answer to add your part about the `ContentPlaceHolder`, including also the source for that part, namely you

Answer (score 0):

If you have a  tag within the  section with a relative url, it fixes up the src path. For example, consider that you may have the head section within a master page which responds to the following URLs.

/foo
/foo/bar
/foo/bar/baz

```
But your script src is "../scripts/script.js"
```

That relative path is only going to be valid for one of those requests. But by using head runat="server", ASP.NET fixes it so it works for all of them.